# odoo auto generate modelform in controller

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view, odoo-website

I come from python Django framework world and i am wondering if it is possible in odoo controller to render model-form like in Django. For example:

```
class PartnerController(http.Controller):
     @http.route('partner/create')
     def create_form(self, **kw):
         model = request.registry['res.partner']
         form = auto generate html form view for the model
         return form
```

Or maybe a way to automatically show an already existing  `ir.ui.view` on the website from the controller.

The ideas is to reuse already defined views and or to not rewrite views for each model every time.

I already know about the website builder but i want something that will be easy to add into a module.

Does someone already do something like that in odoo8/9? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Odoo Controllers can query data and then render templates using that data.
This is done using:

```
return request.website.render("<XMLId-for-my-QWeb-view", {<data dict>})
```

As an example you can check the [Job List](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a77f5cf42faa75a2dd3931d83ad8ea86648248c0/addons/website_hr_recruitment/controllers/main.py#L87) website page:

```
    # Render page
    return request.website.render("website_hr_recruitment.index", {
        'jobs': jobs,
        'countries': countries,
        'departments': departments,
        'offices': offices,
        'country_id': country,
        'department_id': department,
        'office_id': office_id,
    })
```

The data dictionary is then usable in the QWeb template to be rendered.
In this example, the template used is [website_hr_recruitment.index](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a77f5cf42faa75a2dd3931d83ad8ea86648248c0/addons/website_hr_recruitment/views/templates.xml#L11).

Note that you are expected to use QWeb views. AFAIK regular form and list views can't be in the website frontend.

Comment: hi @daniel the Query about "reusable  model-form" as in django , from my understanding it's not possible in odoo , ODOO don't have a generic form template for all model  , What do you think about it?

Comment: QWeb Templates can use other templates, for example using the `t-call` directive. So I would say that an equivalent feature is available.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for the example. if i get it well. in odoo i can only create different views that can be reuse in other views through "t-call" right ? Is it possible to let odoo automatically generate a form for me ? like i understand, i can just call existing one.

Comment: it will be a very good feature if we can do something like `request.website.render("template_name", "model_name")`

Comment: On the backend it does that for Form and List/Tree views. On the website frontend it doesn't.